# UWP removable storage

Tags: c#, uwp

I have an external drive with two files:

- test.mp4
- test.jpg

Trying to enumerate them with this code:

```
string[] imageFiles = Directory.GetFiles(videoPath, movieName + ".*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)  
.Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path))
.Where(path => imageRegEx.IsMatch(path)).ToArray();
```

The UWP app I'm developing does not have a File Type association for `jpg` (because it doesn't handle them), therefore, I have no access to `jpg` files on removable storage. The `Directory.GetFiles` method only returns the `mp4` file.

If I add the file type association to the package manifest, it works properly... the only problem with this is that the application doesn't actually handle `jpgs`, so it shouldn't be allowing the user to open `jpgs` via the "Open With..." menu in Windows.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem so.

You have two alternatives. Use `FileOpenPicker` or `FolderPicker` to let the user choose the files or location which will give you full access to all files on the selected location. You can then even store the retrieved files and folders into `StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList` so that you can access the location anytime in the future without using a picker again.

An alternative would be to just use the `File Association` and after the user opens a unsupported file type let her know that the file cannot be opened by your app.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. Not a big deal.This is actually a low priority feature request on the Xbox version of VLC that I thought might be fun to get some experience on, and I know that it's not worth breaking Windows file associations OR prompting the user with a folder picker.

Comment: Understood. I am not aware of any other good workaround here unfortunately :-(

Comment: If the answer is sufficient, please consider accepting it. This indicates that the question is resolved.